Android Studio Emulators not connecting to internet when set up with proxy
I'm trying to connect my Android Studio emulators to proxies but the the "AndroidWifi" wifi connection has a "limited connection" whenever I configure my proxy settings. The emulators connect without a proxy and the proxy i'm using works fine. I've tried multiple different methods to try to make this work but none have worked so far. I've started the emulator via command line with the -http-proxy flag but when i check my ip in google chrome it's still my local network's IP. I also tried adding the proxy through the proxy tab in the emulator's settings but the "AndroidWifi" wifi shows "limited connection". I set the wifi and mobile settings to unmetered but that didn't help. I also tried setting the Android Studio proxy configuration first but that didn't work either. I'm using mac Sonoma and Android Studio Koala.
I've tried all the different methods of connecting my emulator to a proxy.

Connect your Mac machine and the emulator will pick it up mostly

Your Wifi showing Limited Connection is normal. Apart from your mentioned steps, you need to install CA Certificate from your proxy provider.
Download CA Certificate from official proxy provider website, and then follow the below steps:

Open Settings -> Search "ca certificate" -> Click on first result



Choose "CA Certificate"



Click "Install Anyway"



Choose the downloaded certificate

.png
